# wordpress widget layout

Tags: wordpress, widget

I created a footer sidebar and floated the first `li` elements so the widgets stay horizontally. But how can I do this:

- If there are 2 widgets, then they will have 50% width each.
- If there are 3 widgets, then they will have 33% width.
- Finally if there are 4 widgets then they will have 25% width.

Comment: Please give a little more information so we can help you. Maybe input your css and html here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think there is a way to check how many widgets are in a sidebar.  However, you CAN check if a sidebar has active widgets:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_dynamic_sidebar

So, you can create 4 sidebars for your theme.  Then, in the template file, check to see how many are active by checking each sidebar to see if it has active widgets.  Count the number of active sidebars and you know the # of columns you need.

Then, apply relevant CSS styles to each output as you go.  A bit of a hack but in a lot of ways it helps.

What if someone has 5 widgets?  this way you can indirectly set the # of columns and then lay widgets out vertically per sidebar.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways to accomplish this. First, use [wp_get_sidebars_widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets). Check the length of the returned array to determine how many widgets there are.

Next your three options in my order of preference.

As you output your list items, apply the % width attribute inline.

```
for each (widget in widgets) { 
   echo '<li style="width: ' + 100/widgets.length + '%">';
}
```

Assign a class to each widget and dynamically output some css to size them

```
echo '<style> .widget { width: (same calc is in 1)} </style>
echo '<li class="widget">' ;
```

Do it client side via javascript.

```
 var widgets = document.getElementsByClassName('widgets');
 for (var i = 0; i < widgets.length; i++) {
   widgets[i].style.width = 100 / widgets.length + '%';
 }
```